# How to fix the duplicate character lint error inside regular expression in android?

Tags: java, android, regex, performance, inspect

When I improve my code with Lint, there is inspection error with a duplicate character inside regular expression

```
private static final String IMAGE_LINK_PATTERN = "[(.*)![(.*)]((.*))(.*)](.*)";
private static final String IMAGE_LINK_REPLACE = "<a href=\"$5\" >$1<img src=\"$3\" />$4</a>";
```

> Duplicate character '(' inside character class
>   Duplicate character '.' inside character class
>   Duplicate character '*' inside character class
>   Duplicate character ')' inside character class
>   Duplicate character '(' inside character class
>   Duplicate character ')' inside character class

these is no problem with the regular pattern, so how to suppress this lint error?

Comment: If the character was accidentally duplicated, remove it. If the character class was meant to be a group, replace the brackets with parentheses.

Comment: Finally, I extract the string into String Resource, it skips the lint

Comment: Skipping the lint is a non-sense, you should fix the bug you were warned about. Your `IMAGE_LINK_PATTERN` seems to be completely broken.